# How to add HTMLBody Signature?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to add my signature at the end of a generated Outlook email.

I changed my (`.HTMLBody = msg`) to (`.HTMLBody = msg & .HTMLBody`). This got my signature to display but my msg text vanished. When I removed the `.HTMLBody` at the end and use my original code, my text appears formatted correctly but no signature.

```vb
Sub Email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Path As String
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    msg = "<p>Hello World,</p><br>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .Display
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Fruits Stock " & Path
        .HTMLBody = msg & "Hello World" & .HTMLBody
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when creating a loop for sending emails with a specific signature. In my case I had to pick from one of a few signatures as it could vary for each email.

I passed the signature name as a string variable `Signame` into a separate function, used to add the signature onto an email.

```vb
'Code trimmed down a lot to just relevant bits
Sub Email()
'Create email here
Dim Email as outlook.mailitem, OutApp as Object
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Email = OutApp.Createitem(olMailItem)
'Email Content:
Email.Htmlbody = "<p>Hello World</p>" & AddSig("My_Signature")
Email.display
End Sub

Function AddSig(Signame as string)
If Len(Signame) > 0 Then
    Dim fso As Object, ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"): Set ts = fso.GetFile(Environ("Appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & Signame & ".htm").OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    Signame = Replace(Signame, " ", "%20")
    AddSig = "<br>" & Replace(ts.ReadAll, _
        Signame & "_files", _
        Replace(Environ("Appdata"), " ", "%20") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & Signame & "_files")
End If
End Function
```

Substitute your signature name where I put "My_Signature".

This doesn't work for signatures with a space in their name, despite my efforts with `Signame = Replace(Signame, " ", "%20")` - it's something to do with the HTML. I just renamed my signatures to remove all spaces.

Comment: This makes some sense to me. I am trying to add the Set Email = Application.Createitem(olMailItem) but I get Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this method or property. Not sure what I need to enable. I also did something where I declared the Signature as a variant which almost seemed to work but my signature will flicker then be overwritten by the body text of "hello world"

Comment: Sorry, forgot we're in Excel vba not outlook vba - you need to `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` as per the code in your question. Editing the answer to suit.

Comment: @user17420363, Your code works just fine in my Outlook or Excel VBA!!! It might be some Outlook custom settings. What version of Office you are using?

Comment: .16 I think. I am starting to believe my issue might actually be related to the very very strict security policies after researching the error message I get when trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a search using Google about [`MailItem.HTMLBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody)?

It shows an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody):

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
 
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 
 
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 
 
 'Create email item 
 
 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 
 With objMail 
 
 'Set body format to HTML 
 
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
 
 .HTMLBody = _ 
 
 "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 
 
 .Display 
 
 End With 
 
End Sub
```

If you want your email to be in HTMl format they you need to set a flag:

`.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML`

---

Lookup the [`MailItem.BodyFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) property.